# Logging to Redis for Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, redis, analytics

I run a Rails application on Heroku, and would like to log all log messages to Redis instead of (or in addition to) the standard logging to file/stdout, for purposes of auditing and analyzing the logs. Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find ledis - a simple redis based logger at https://github.com/ahoward/ledis